# How to create a advanced text replacement database in VB

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, dictionary, replace

i have been trying to create a function that will allow me to write a word in a `richtextbox` and i will be shown a list of alternate words and their meanings  or i will be able to press a `button` and replace the word i wrote in with the alternate texts .

i have tried toing this with `Dictionary`

```
    Public Sub wordget()

    wordDictionary = New Dictionary(Of String, String())
    wordDictionary.Add("code", {"lines", "script"})
    wordDictionary.Add("dwell", {"holding", "denn", "space"})
End Sub
```

umm i then say `dim lastword as String = richtextbox1.text.split(" ").last`

then i check if lastword  is equal to wordDictionary key , if it is i then replace `lastword` with the first string in the array .

this method is not really good because i would not be able to display the words and their meaning but just the words .

```
Private Sub TextDisplay_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextDisplay.TextChanged
    Dim lastword As String = TextDisplay.Text.Split(" ").Last
    Dim val As Integer

    If wordDictionary.ContainsKey(lastword) Then
        For Each wstr As String() In wordDictionary.Values
            TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text.Replace(lastword, wstr(val))
        Next
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub NextButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NextButton.Click

    Val = Val() + 1

End Sub
```

i am having trouble getting the code to function the way i want it to , if i write in  `dwell` it will replace `dwell` with  the word `code` . i do not know how to manipulate the arrays .

how can i accomplish this using another method or this method ?

Comment: Sounds very [clbuttic](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-.aspx)

Comment: "*this method is not really good.*" Unless you tell us *why* you think that this method is "not good", we cannot tell you how to make it better.

Comment: edited it . i will be unable add the meaning of each word in the the arrays . I'm new to using dictionaries so its a bit difficult to use. I was thinking of creating a database but that may be even more troublesome.

Comment: @MarcB i really understand that . did you mean ambiguous ? it was , I edited the code .

Comment: no. I meant as in doing word filtering via simple string substitution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've got how to access your Dictionary a bit muddled. I think this is what you meant:

[Edit: I have replaced the code snippet with the entire code I used to test.]

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim wordDictionary As Dictionary(Of String, String())

    Private Sub TextDisplay_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextDisplay.TextChanged
        Dim lastword As String = TextDisplay.Text.Split(" "c).Last

        For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String()) In wordDictionary
            If kvp.Value.Contains(lastword) Then
                TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text.Replace(lastword, kvp.Key)
                ' move the cursor to the end of the text
                TextDisplay.Select(TextDisplay.TextLength, TextDisplay.TextLength)
                ' operation has been done, exit the search
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        wordDictionary = New Dictionary(Of String, String())
        wordDictionary.Add("code", New String() {"lines", "script"})
        wordDictionary.Add("dwell", New String() {"holding", "denn", "space"})
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: i'm not getting anything , no errors and no results . which is strange

Comment: the isue starts wt where you have `If kvp.Value.Contains(lastword) Then`

Comment: I wrote that code with just one RTB on a Form and it worked. Could you perhaps have other code interacting with the RTB at the same time? To show what I used, I've edited my answer.

Comment: yeah I do , the RTB is read only so i enter the text this way `TextDisplay.text = TextDisplay.text + "a"` if the `A` key is pressed

Comment: Have you tried just my example code in a new project to verify that it works the way you want? We could then move on, and perhaps you could edit your question to include the method which is entering the text.

Comment: @RuchmairDixon Which version of VS are you using? I just edited my answer (the initialisation of wordDictionary) to make it compatible with VB in VS2008. What I do to test is type in `lines`, which is immediately changed to `code`.

Comment: I use VS2012 . the code still isnt working. i  am unable to pinpoint the issue . i will have to try another method .

Answer (score 0):

```
    Private Sub TextDisplay_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextDisplay.TextChanged
    Dim lastword As String = TextDisplay.Text.Split(" ").Last
    For Each wstr As String In wordDictionary.Keys
        If (TextDisplay.Text.Contains(wstr)) Then
            TextDisplay.Text = TextDisplay.Text.Replace(lastword, ) 'replace with the value at 0 position in the array 
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```